# Details in Lemma 10.23 of Atiyah Macdonald

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am stuck filling in some details in the proof of Lemma 10.23 in Atiyah-Macdonald. For reference, I have included a screenshot of the lemma and proof below.

I am having trouble filling in the details of the line "From this we see, by induction on $n$, that $\operatorname{Ker} \alpha_n = 0$... or $\operatorname{Coker} \alpha_n = 0$". I see that in the base case ($n = 0$), we have that $\alpha_0 : A / A \to B / B$, so $\alpha_0$ is the zero-map, and both the kernel and cokernel of $\alpha_0$ are $0$. For the inductive step, however, I'm not sure how to use the given long exact sequence.

I have tried assuming that $\operatorname{Coker}\alpha_{n+1} \neq 0$, and showing that as a consequence of this and the inductive hypothesis, $\operatorname{Ker}\alpha_{n+1} = 0$. If $\operatorname{Coker} \alpha_n = 0$, then we get that $\operatorname{Coker} G_n(\phi) \to \operatorname{Coker} \alpha_{n+1}$ is surjective, but I don't see why this would imply that $\operatorname{Ker} \alpha_n \to \operatorname{Coker} G_n(\phi)$ is injective. I get similarly stuck if I assume instead that $\operatorname{Ker} \alpha_n = 0$.

Any help filling in these details would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that in this proof we have the assumption that $G(\phi)$ is surjective (or injective), so when proving the statement $\operatorname{Coker}\alpha_n = 0$ ($\operatorname{Ker}\alpha_n = 0$, resp.), we can use the fact that $\operatorname{Coker} G_n(\phi) = 0$ ($\operatorname{Ker}G_n(\phi) = 0$, resp.). Thus in the inductive step for case ii), we use both $\operatorname{Coker}\alpha_{n} = 0$ and $\operatorname{Coker} G_n(\phi) = 0$ to show that $\operatorname{Coker}\alpha_{n+1}$ to be $0$. The next sentence actually uses $\operatorname{Coker} G_n(\phi) = 0$ again, noting that this implies that $\operatorname{Ker}\alpha_{n+1}\to \operatorname{Ker}\alpha_n$ is surjective. The argument in case i) is similar.

Comment: Thanks! I was misinterpreting the parenthetical "(case i)" and "(case ii)" as declaring two different cases that we would then deal with, rather than referring back to the cases declared in the statement of the lemma. This makes sense now!